# Initialized static variable becomes null

Tags: java, apache-flink, guice

I have a simple class like so:

```
class MyClass {
  private static SomeClass object = null;

  public void init(Someclass injectedObject) {
    object = injectedObject;
  }
}
```

I init this class in my Guice module:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Provides @Singleton
  public SomeClass getStuff() {
    SomeClass injectObject = new SomeClass();
    MyClass.init(injectObject);
  }

}
```

But when I package the my jar and submit it as a job to Flink runtime, I get an error saying `NullPointerException: object in MyClass in null`

I have even tried adding this to my method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Guice stuff
}

public void doStuff() {
  MyClass.init(injectedObject);
}
```

Am I missing something? Why is an initialized variable getting reset to null in Flink runtime?

Comment: Is Flink complaining because you initialize `object` to `null` in the declaration and doesn't even get to the `init()` method? I think your assumption that the varialbe is getting "reset" needs to be tested. Maybe you should add some `System.out.println` statements, at least if there is a way for you to view this output, to trace the execution. Does the error occur while executing `init()` or does it happen before that? (IDK what Flink is, but I'm just looking at the code here as you posted it.)

Comment: With that said, why are you using a `static` field at all here? Can you do this with a non-static member field instead? Remember that a `static` field is associated with the class and not with any specific instance. Generally, `static` should only be used when you have a value that logically belongs with the class.

Comment: With Flink, you cannot inject non-serializable objects into jobs. You have to get/build them during the job. I'm essentially trying to build a singleton cache and fetching it in a Flink job.

Comment: I don't understand how that means the field has to be static. You could just as easily make it non-static, right?

Comment: Check some examples on how to build a singleton from scratch. That'll answer your question about why it has to be static.

Comment: But you aren't building a singleton from scratch here. Instead, you are using a dependency injection container. Also, `SomeClass` is the singleton, not `MyClass`, so you don't need a `static` field in `MyClass`.

Comment: On top of that `getStuff()` is declared to return an object of type `SomeClass`, but there is no `return`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to inject into static fields using Guice:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(SomeClass.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    requestStaticInjection(MyClass.class);
  }
}

class MyClass {
  @Inject private static SomeClass object;
  // no init method needed
}
```

However, it would be even better if you can omit the `static` field altogether:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(SomeClass.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    bind(MyClass.class);
  }
}

class MyClass {
  private final SomeClass object;
  
  @Inject 
  MyClass(SomeClass object) {
    this.object = object;
  }
}
```

Now you can request `MyClass` instances either by injecting them or requesting them directly from the `injector`, and they will all have access to the same `SomeClass` instance.